# Concept of Digest authentication - does it really work?

Tags: security

As far as i understand, Digest authentication (which is a one way operation) hash the password and transmit the hashed data to the server. The server then will use the stored password, hash it and compare with equality against the received hash password. Supposed to be safe from middle man attack.

What i don't understand is if i'm the middle man hacker, i don't need the original password. Well just use the hash password since that is the one which the server will compared against.

So what's the use of this Digest authentication mechanism?
Doesn't seem to work from this general overview.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Digest authentication doesn't work quite the way you've described.

1. The server doesn't store the unhashed password. The server stores a hash of Username:realm:password.
2. The client doesn't send the same hash for every authentication.

Digest auth is a challenge-response protocol. To start the process the client requests a protected URL and the server responds with the realm and a [nonce](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce). The client uses the realm and nonce to calculate:

```
md5(md5(username:realm:password):nonce:md5(httpMethod:uri))
```

The nonce causes each authentication to produce a different hash value, and in doing so prevents replay attacks. Further, it does provide some (weak) protection against attackers listening in on your communication because the plaintext password doesn't pass over the wire, although this does not stop an attacker from cracking the hash once they have it.

Comment: @yapkm01: Does this answer your question, is anything unclear?

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot! By the way what do you mean by realm here?

Comment: Realm is a string that is displayed to the user when prompting them for their username and password during the authentication process. The value of this string varies depending on the system that is doing the authentication, but is generally something that helps the user know what login credentials they're supposed to use. For example, if you were doing digest authentication for gmail, the realm might be something like "gmail.com".